# How to get cs files for xml schemas (xsd)

Tags: c#, xsd

I'm new in C# developpment and I want to know the procedure to get one CS file for each XSD schema I have.

I have 3 xsd files (A.xsd, B.xsd and Common.xsd). Both A and B have Common as import. I've tried "xsd.exe" and "xsd2code.exe" without success.

- "xsd.exe"

  1. Cannot generate classes because no top-level elements with complex type were found into "Common.xsd".
  2. Files "A.cs" and "B.cs" are generate but the code of "Common.xsd" is in each files.

     ---
- "xsd2code.exe"

  1. "Common.cs" is well generated with the namespace I've choosen, "MyNamespace.Common".
  2. Other files could not be generated because of unspecified types however I use the "MyNamespace.Common" as custom usings ("/cu" option).

     ---

Does someone have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reference all the schemas that are in the import or include chain.

Try this:

```
xsd /c A.xsd B.xsd Common.xsd
```

**Edit:** However this will mean that all the classes are in one file.

If you want them split out into different files you have two options:

1. Manually split them out. I know this is a generated file but if your source schemas are fairly static then it's a one off exercise.
2. Use svcutil.exe instead. However this is much more complicated and actually you may not even be able to do this unless your schemas all abide by certain guidelines. If you are interested see below for the process.

If you fancy option 2 above then here is the general process:

1. Extract the types from Common.xsd using the /dconly flag on svcutil. This will generate a class file with your common types.
2. Compile this class into an assembly
3. Extract the types from A.xsd using the /r flag and referencing your CommonTypes.dll assembly.
4. Do the same for B.xsd

However, this approach is based on svcutil using the DataContractSerializer to do the work, as the /r flag is not available to XmlSerializer. And this will only work if the your schemas adhere to the rather strict DCS rules (can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733112.aspx).

If these rules are not adhered to then svcutil will fall back to using XmlSerializer which does not support /r flag.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, it works but all is in one file. My goal is to have one cs file per schema.

Comment: Have expanded answer please see.

Comment: I had already thought about your first option. But, for my point of view, a manual action after an automatic one is tricky. Your second option is, in fact, much more compicated but work well. Your process help me and thanks a lot for that.